# Disable .rodata indirection for local constants

Tags: c, gcc

When i have local data defined inside a function, it gets placed into .rodata section. This means that .text section will contain relative reference (//1) to an absolute address (//2) inside the .text, which in turn points to the data (//3) inside .rodata.

```
int function() { int a[] = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 103}; }

// Undesirable:
00000000 <.text.function>:
/---/
6:    4b07            ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; (24 <function+0x24>) //1
/---/
24:   00000000        .word   0x00000000 //2 absolute address of .rodata
00000000 <.rodata>:    // absolute address will be replaced by linker
0:    00000061        .word   0x00000061 //3
4:    00000062        .word   0x00000062
8:    00000063        .word   0x00000063
c:    00000064        .word   0x00000064
10:   00000065        .word   0x00000065
14:   00000067        .word   0x00000067
```

I understand that keeping data and code separate is admirable in general, but in the case of my embedded system I want to have local data and function code entangled. I want that the [pc, #28] relative pointer would point directly to the data location and the array values should be directly in the .text section.

I can do something similar using linkerscript but the absolute address will still be in there, and I don't want the function .text section to contain any absolute addresses.

```
// Undesirable:
.text.function : {
    *(.text.function)
    filename.o(.rodata)
}
00000000 <.text.function>:
/---/
6:    4b07            ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; (24 <function+0x24>)
/---/
24:   00000000        .word   0x00000028 // address of next line
28:   00000061        .word   0x00000061
/---/
```

Are there any compiler flags or other methods to force gcc to include data alongside the code and skip this additional indirection?

**edit:**
To further clarify what I am asking, I'd like to point out some solutions, that won't work. Adding `static const` to the array will force it to be stored inside .rodata section and is therefore the exact opposite of what I want. Adding `__attribute__((section(".text")))` won't work because this question is about local variables and local variables can't have section attributes. Unfortunately `-fpic` or `-fpie` don't seem to work either, instead those depend on runtime linker to replace absolute addresses.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude data is stored in .rodata but copied to stack before being used

Comment: Have you tried -O2/-O3?

Comment: @PSkocik yes, i tried all optimization levels, and as long as the data was used, it changed nothing

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Unfortunately no, this is not a duplicate. His problem is that he wants data to be in flash and it was solved by marking data `static const` and placed into .rodata. I want in fact the opposite: I don't want data to end up in .rodata...

Comment: @FlorianWeimer As for the second answer on that question, "section attribute cannot be specified for local variables" and my question is specifically about local variables.